# Grub has overwritten my main hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub, boot-loader, grub-legacy, mx-linux

I installed MX Linux into my ssd to dual boot it with PopOS but I chose the grub option because it said that I can dual boot easily with it. But that one choice doomed my life. my main hard disk has been overwritten by grub and grub now doesn't recognise PopOS as a choice. I have been researching for months while using mx but nothing, absolutely nothing.

Tried to edit the grub.cfg file, tried to edit the mx boot options, tried to literally **remove** the ssd and try to force boot the hard drive but it was of no use, nothing I found from here, youtube, mx forums, grub's website, nothing could help. I wanted to install windows as a replacement to the other os on my hard drive but for some reason grub prevented everything. I can provide you any details just please help me I feel like my pc is stuck in this state with no other way to even replace the os'es. I'm literally stuck with MX Linux

Comment: Grub does not actively prevent installation of any operating system. Can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: "_I have been researching for months_" really?

Comment: This includes the fdisk output & a lot more. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I have re-read this several times, and I am still not clear what you mean. "overwritten your hard drive?" Did it wipe out the hard drive? GRUB should only write to the boot parts of the hard drive, not the entire drive. What does your drive's partition table look like ("sudo fdisk -l" as  Hermann said)? In the meantime, I do suggest you stop using the drive as continued usage reduces chances of recovery; Go buy a cheap empty hard drive to install a working system on and use that for daily use, setting the old drive aside until you can attempt recovery.